# queue jms [wso2] message broker. callback service

Tags: java, wso2, messagebroker, jms-queue, wso2-esb

Good morning, I am currently managing a queue jms [wso2] message broker.
I have a java client who sends a message in the queue and a java ServletContextListener which activates every time a message is being delivered.
And everything works ok.
My bosses have asked me now if it was possible that once the message arrives in the queue, it automatically makes a call to a service.
I was reading something like [wso2] ESB Message Processor.
My questions are:

1) Is it possible to do such a thing without using [wso2] ESB? but only [wso2] message Broker.
If you have some ideas.

2) at this point [wso2] ESB would be a consumer and a call from them?

3) If someone can give me an example of how to handle the ESB once the message ne [wso2] Message Broker has arrived.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I got it right, but here are some thoughts that come into my mind.

1.) I'm not familiar with wso2 mb (using activemq) but I assume that its not possible according to the documentation

2.) Yes, the esb acts as a message consumer (like your java client) and can do various things then. You can call other services, forward the message to another queue etc...Maybe the ESB can do the things you're servlet is doing

3.)You can create a simple proxy in esb that takes the jms message and forwards it to your servlet,service or whatever. There are plenty of cases, regarding jms messages the following link might help.

[ESB JMS](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/ESB+as+Both+a+JMS+Producer+and+Consumer)

One other thing I'm thinking of, if you send your jms message to a jms topic from your java client, you can then create several consumers for the same message. So your existing implementation will subscribe to that topic and you can create a simple second client (or use the esb) that connects to that topic as well. Both will receive the same message and can do whatever processing is needed.

Hope that helps.